# ffmpeg is not decoding HEVC video correctly when I use multiple QPs

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, hevc, h.265

I am doing HEVC based video coding on a video file. We have modified HEVC encoder and now it assigns three different QP values to three different regions in single frame. The output YUV file from HEVC encoder has accurate outputs. But when I use ffmpeg to convert encoded HEVC file to mp4, the results are really bad. Color of video distort.

How can I deal with this problem?
[output from ffmpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ5aC.png)
[YUV frame from HEVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GBSy.jpg)